# Pandas Create Column of Numpy Arrays Given Min and Max in Other Columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'min':[1,2,3],'max':[4,5,6]})
df
   min  max
0    1    4
1    2    5
2    3    6
```

I need to add a third column called "arrays" that is a set of arrays generated from the "min" and "max" columns (with 1 added to the "max" value).
For example, using data from the first row, `min = 1` and `max = 4`:

```
np.arange(1, 5)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

So I would need that resulting stored in the new "arrays" column in the first row.

Here is the desired result:

```
   min  max     arrays
0    1    4  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    2    5  [2, 3, 4, 5]
2    3    6  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'min':[1,2,3],'max':[4,5,6]})

df['arrays'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.arange(x['min'], x['max']+1), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   min  max        arrays
0    1    4  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    2    5  [2, 3, 4, 5]
2    3    6  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension with `range`

```
df['arrays'] = [list(range(m, mx+1)) for m, mx in zip(df['min'], df['max'])]


Out[1015]:
   min  max        arrays
0    1    4  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    2    5  [2, 3, 4, 5]
2    3    6  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```